# Google maps api v2 zooming near the marker

Tags: android, android-maps

I am using Google maps api v2 in android. I have placed a marker by using latitude and longitude . The marker is shown at correct place , but i want the the map should show area around the marker only .i.e i want to zoom to markers position when the map is shown so it shows nearby region of the marker only..any help would be great.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

pass your current location in this function where you have placed your marker.

```
private void moveToCurrentLocation(LatLng currentLocation)
{   
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation,15));
    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
    // Zoom out to zoom level 10, animating with a duration of 2 seconds.
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);


}
```

Comment: @ Arsal Imam I glad it helped..:)

Comment: nice work bro... if you can please explain last 2 animation camera more..

Answer (score 22):

Provide marker position.

```
private void pointToPosition(LatLng position) {
    //Build camera position
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(position)
            .zoom(17).build();
    //Zoom in and animate the camera.
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}
```